# awk print line of file2 based on condition of file1

Tags: awk

I have two files:

cat file1:

```
0 xxx
1 yyy
1 zzz
0 aaa
```

cat file2:

```
A bbb
B ccc
C ddd
D eee
```

How do I get the following output using awk:

```
B ccc
C ddd
```

My question is, how do I print lines from file2 only if a certain field in file1 (i.e. field 1) matches a certain value (i.e. 1)?

Additional information:

Files file1 and file2 have an equal number of lines.

Files file1 and file2 have millions of lines and cannot be read into memory.

file1 has 4 columns.

file2 has approximately 1000 columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No as clean as a awk solution

```
$ paste file2 file1 | sed '/0/d' | cut -f1
B
C
```

You mentioned something about millions of lines, in order to just do a single pass through the files, I'd resort to python. Something like this perhaps (python 2.7):

```
with open("file1") as fd1, open("file2") as fd2:
    for l1, l2 in zip(fd1, fd2):
        if not l1.startswith('0'):
            print l2.strip()
```

Comment: Python is definitely an option (which I intended to use, if sputnick hadn't provided me with the awk solution). Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I ended up using your paste solution, which used less than 20MB of memory and ran in less than 30 seconds. I did: paste file1 file2 | awk '{if($1==1) print}' | cut -f2

Comment: @tommy.carstensen - nice, glad I could help.

Answer (score 3):

Try doing this (a bit obfuscated):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$1}NR!=FNR&&a[FNR]' file1 file2
```

On multiples lines it can be clearer (reminder, `awk` works like this : `condition{action}` :

```
awk '
    NR==FNR{arr[NR]=$1}
    NR!=FNR && arr[FNR] 
' file1 file2
```

If I remove the "clever" parts of the snippet :

```
awk '
    if (NR == FNR) {arr[NR]=$1}
    if (NR != FNR && arr[FNR]) {print $0} 
' file1 file2
```

When `awk` find a condition alone (without action) like `NR!=FNR && arr[FNR]`, it print by default on `STDOUT` implicitly  is the expressions is `TRUE` (> 0)

### Explanations

- `NR` is the number of the current record from the start of input
- `FNR` is the ordinal number of the current record **in the current file** (so `NR` is different than `FNR` on the second file)
- `arr[NR]=$1` : feeding array `arr` with indice of the current `NR` with the first column
- if `NR!=FNR` we are in the next file and if the value of the array if `1`, then we print

Comment: It works on the input I specified. However, I have multiple fields in file1 and file2. I will edit my question.

Comment: post edited accordingly with explanations and the not needed `print` has been removed

Comment: Indeed it does. Thank you. I'll accept the answer later today. Thanks for also providing an explanation!

Comment: I can't actually use your method. It requires too much memory. I have to go with the solution provided by wau.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '{
  getline value <"file2";
  if ($1)
    print value;
}' file1
```

Comment: I get a syntax error:
awk: {getline value <"file2" if ($1) print value;}
awk:                         ^ syntax error

Comment: if it's all on one line, you must add a semicolon after the getline command (I updated the code to add it)

Comment: Your solution works as well. I will test them both (yours and the one from sputnick) and see, which one is faster.

Comment: I also exceed my 100MB memory threshold, when I use this method. It seems I will have to resort to Python.